# Task.Run() Inside of a Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We have an Azure Function App (timer triggered) on a Consumption plan for testing purpose. The App fist fires a bunch of Stored Procedures on a SQL Server. We use Task.Run() and inside of it it's just a Synchronous operation to run an SP on the Server. It's a fire and forgets tasks that we require and the Exceptions/Errors from SQL are logged to the table inside of the SQL Server. This particular Azure App is a plan to migrate our SQL Agent Jobs (as we are moving towards a PaaS Database) to the cloud. Moreover, the Function App triggers an SP across multiple databases. So a single Task.Run for each DB.

The thing is the execution of the SP might take around 20 minutes to complete itself. I see that around 19 minutes the Connection is dropped. So I see that an SP was was started let's say at 5:00 AM and with appropriate logging inside of an SP, it went on till 5:19 AM and then it stopped (no success log). So I believe the SQLConnection from C# is dropped. The consumption plan default is 5 minutes. So if it's a timeout issue then why still I can continue till 19 minutes and then only it's dropped. I have observed this behavior for some days now.

I cannot arrive at a feasible explanation of the above behavior.

Comment: Might sound silly but you could try doing some background logging to the console every minute to indicate that your app is still performing work. This act itself might allow the functions runtime to keep your app alive. Though 19 minutes for a serverless function to run is a long time. Might be worth deploying it as a triggered webjob instead

Comment: Hi @ConnorDickson Thanks for the response. The thing is I have logged in the SQL Server and it seems that the long-running SP does continue till 19 minutes then it suddenly dies which I believe might be the reason when the SQLConnection C# object is disposed of by the Azure Function. So just trying to get my head around as how this is allowed if the maximum timeout is of 10 minutes for a consumption plan (which I have configured in the host file). I just connect to DB from a Task.Run using an SQLConnection and do an EndExecuteNonQuery on a Command which just triggers a long-running SP.

Answer (score 3):

Maximum timeout for azure functions in consumption plan is 10min:

[image]

Change plan to support longer timeout or you can use **Durable functions** (intended for long-running tasks).

> Durable Functions is an extension of Azure Functions that lets you
> write stateful functions in a serverless compute environment. The
> extension lets you define stateful workflows by writing orchestrator
> functions and stateful entities by writing entity functions using the
> Azure Functions programming model. Behind the scenes, the extension
> manages state, checkpoints, and restarts for you, allowing you to
> focus on your business logic.

Refs:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#function-app-timeout-duration
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-long-running-serverless-workflow-with-durable-functions/

Comment: Hi @Tomasz, thanks for the reply. I still can't get this figure out as to why the underlying SQL Connection to the database server went on till 19 minutes? I have logged in the Stored Procedure that proves this and this stored procedure is ONLY called via the Azure Function using ADO.NET. So it seems to me that after around 19 minutes the SQLConnection object is disposed off, thus the SP stops in between and not make it to completion. So can't figure out how this works and would changing to a premium plan would help? I believe the Awaiting time on an Async operation also is counted in timeout?